# Cakephp associations custom methods

Tags: cakephp

I was wondering the following, if I have these two Models:

```
Author
Book
```

And every author has written a few books, together with some other authors.

So basically every book has:

`Title`
`MainAuthor`
`CoAuthor`

Now in my application I need to check a lot if a Auther is either a `MainAuthor` or a `CoAuthor`. My idea was to create a method in the `Author` model to check this.

So basically, I can do something like this:

`$this->Author->hasWritten($bookId)`

However, I was wondering, what do you think of this approuch, and how would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems correcto to me to do that, but I think a `Book` could has two main `Authors` or maybe more, and other many more `CoAuthors`. 
In your explanation, I understood that one `Book` only have one `MainAuthor` and one `CoAuthor`. If that is realy the system it's fine like you describe, but If it's like I write you have to think in creating an Help table.

Comment: No you're right. I've simplified the problem by using books/authors. A book can indeed have only one author, and only one coauthor

Comment: If thats so. I think your approuch is correct.
Create a table for 'Authors', and a table for 'Books'. In 'Books' table I would create this two fields, 'MainAuthor' to get the id of mais author, and 'CoAuthor' if the 'Book' has two Authors. If the book only have one author, keep CoAuthor field null/empty.